# How do I check if selected text on a web only consists of words in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, selection

In vanilla Javascript, I am trying to determine whether the text selected by a user on a webpage all consists of words (excluding the symbols).

To take an example,

Let's say we have texts like below somewhere on the webpage.

> **Hello, a text for the example!** *(When selected all)*

Should result in `['Hello', 'a', 'text', 'for', 'the', 'example']`

However,

> Hel**lo, a text for the example!** *(Leaving out the first three letters)*

Should result in `['a', 'text', 'for', 'the', 'example']` since `Hello` was not completely selected as a word.

So far, I have a `getSelectionText` function which brings all the selected text.

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type !== "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

// Just adding the function as listeners.
document.onmouseup = document.onkeyup = function() {
    console.log(getSelectionText());
};
```

Is there any good way to tweak my function to make it work as I mentioned?

Comment: How should the regex know, that 'llo' isn't a full Word? Regex doesn't know any languages.

Comment: @PoulBak Thank you for pointing that out! I removed the `regex` tag!

Comment: You would need to compare the selected text to the entire text to find out if partial works are selected. Or use a dictionary of known words to compare everything against.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for your opinion! but since it's a random text on any webpage(because this code is for the chrome extension), How do I get the entire text while it could not be a whole paragraph?

Comment: Well, one, you should [edit] your question to include all requirements and information needed to answer it. Beyond that, you could just grab the selected text, then go backwards/forwards over the text surrounding the selection until you get to another word boundary.

Comment: When you create the range, try to also cover the text next to it. Then you can check whether there is a word boundary (e.g. whitespace) or whether the user selection starts in the middle of a word.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for your opinion! I will edit my question on the fly when it's needed! and would using `range` would work?

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for your opinion! Since I am new to javascript, can you tell me a way to implement that in code? Would `addrange()` work?

Comment: @Poream3387 Tbh I haven't used the `Range` API in ages. I don't think you need `addRange`, you rather need a way to find the contents of the node (or parent nodes?) at the start of the first range. That should be easy in plain text, it'll become a bit harder when the range starts at e.g. the first character of a `<span>` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main obstacle in achieving what you want is how to tell your program what a "word" actually is.

One way would be to have a full dictionary of all English words.

```js
const setOfAllEnglishWords = new Set([
  "Hello",
  "a",
  "text",
  "for",
  "the",
  "example"
  // ... many many more
]);

const selection = "lo, a text for the example!";
const result = selection
  .replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/g, "") // remove punctuation by replacing anything that is not a letter or a digit with the empty string
  .split(/\s+/)                   // split text into words by using 1 or more whitespace as the break point
  .filter(word => setOfAllEnglishWords.has(word));

console.log(result);
```

This could require a good amount of memory. Based on a quick Google Search, Oxford English dictionary has approximately `218632` words. The average word length is `4.5` letters and JS stores `2` bytes per character, giving us `218632 * (4.5 * 2) = 1967688 B = 1.967 MB`, which could take up to 1min to download on a slow 3G connection.

A better approach might be to just build the dictionary of words yourself each time the page loads by collecting all unique words on the page.

```js
function getSetOfWordsOnPage() {
  const walk = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT
  );

  const dict = new Set();
  let n;
  while ((n = walk.nextNode())) {
    for (const word of n.textContent
      .replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/g, "")
      .split(/\s+/)
      .map(word => word.trim())
      .filter(word => !!word)) {
      dict.add(word);
    }
  }
  return dict;
}

const setOfWordsOnThePage = getSetOfWordsOnPage();

function getSelectionText() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    return window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type !== "Control") {
    return document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return "";
}

// Just adding the function as listeners.
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const result = getSelectionText()
    .replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/g, "") // remove punctuation
    .split(/\s+/) // split text into words
    .filter(word => setOfWordsOnThePage.has(word));
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Show result</button>
<p>this is some text</p>
<p>again this is a text!!!!!</p>
<p>another,example,of,a,sentence</p>
```

---

Maybe we can take this even further. Do we even need to remember the words? It seems that the definition "a word is text surrounded by spaces" is enough.

Furthermore, as mentioned in the comment below by the OP, we also have the bug of the above solution matching partially selected words if the selected section is also a valid word.

To reduce the unnecessary overhead of remembering the words on the page as well as solve the partial-selection-of-valid-word bug, we can check the contents of the left-most (anchor) and right-most (focus) nodes of the selected area right after the selection and just ignore them if they contain additional unselected text.

The assumption we're making here is that, for any arbitrary selection of text, we can have at most 2 partially selected words, one at each selection end.

*Note:* the approach bellow also handles capitalization by assuming `THIS`, `tHiS`, and `this` are all the same word.

```js
function removePunctuation(string) {
  return string.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s]/g, " ");
}

function splitIntoWords(string) {
  return removePunctuation(string)
    .split(/\s+/)
    .map(word => word.toLowerCase().trim())
    .filter(word => !!word);
}

function getSelectedWords() {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const words = splitIntoWords(selection.toString());

  if (selection.anchorNode) {
    const startingsWords = splitIntoWords(selection.anchorNode.textContent);
    if (words[0] !== startingsWords[0]) {
      words.shift(); // remove the start since it's not a whole word
    }
  }

  if (selection.focusNode) {
    const endingWords = splitIntoWords(selection.focusNode.textContent);
    if (words[words.length - 1] !== endingWords[endingWords.length - 1]) {
      words.pop(); // remove the end since it's not a whole word
    }
  }

  return words;
}

// Just adding the function as listeners.
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(getSelectedWords());
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Show result</button>
<p><div>this is</div> <div>some text</div></p>
<p><span>again</span><span> </span><span>this</span><span> </span><span>is</span><span> </span><span>a</span> <span>text</span><span>!!!!!</span></p>
<p>another,example,of,a,sentence</p>
```

*Note:* this code will still break if you have words broken up into multiple html elements like this `<span>w</span><span>o</span><span>r</span><span>d</span>`. This scenario breaks our definition of a word and to solve it you'd need to include some sort of dictionary as well to test word validity, essentially combining the last 2 solutions above.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! However, I have a question with one exception. What if the selected sentence is `I say hell` from `I say hello` but there is actually a word `hell` from other paragraphs on the same webpage? Wouldn't this still give me `hell` in the result??

Comment: You're right, a correct substring would still get matched.

Comment: Would there be any way to get around that problem?

Comment: @Poream3387 Checkout my edit. I added a solution for it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed solution! But I have a question since I'm quite new to JS. What does these `if (window.getSelection)`, `if (selection.anchorNode)` check?

Comment: Glad to help mate :). The check `if (window.getSelection)` is there because I copied it from your code and I assume you found it somewhere else :). Why it might be needed is because some browsers might not have this API and we might need a fallback solution. The check `if (selection.anchorNode)` is only there because when there's no text selected, if you run the `getSelectedWords` function, `selection.anchorNode` and `selection.focusNode` will both be `null` and thus calling `.textContent` on them will give an error. In other words, that check is just for protection when no text is selected.